# Linq query to return items of list with another list inside it

Tags: c#, .net, api, linq, http

I'm new to Linq queries, and this problem encountered me (after the other dev was fired).
I'm consuming a freight API that returns a list of "n" freight prices for each product/item in the requisition. The response classes are:

```
public class FreightSimulation
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ItemFreight> Freights { get; set; }
}

public class ItemFreight
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I have a response model for 2 items (but it can also be "n" items), one of them have 5 freights possibilities, with no errors, but the other has two errors meaning that one company doesn't have a freight service for that item:

```
var response = new FreightSimulation
    {
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
                Id = 1,
                Freights = new List<ItemFreight>
                {
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 10,
                        Days = 8,
                        Company = new Company
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        },
                        Type = new Type
                        {
                            Id = 3
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 20,
                        Days = 3,
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 8
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 20,
                        Days = 10,
                        Company = new Company
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 35,
                        Days = 4,
                        Company = new Company
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        },
                        Type = new Type
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 15,
                        Days = 6,
                        Company = new Company
                        {
                            Id = 7468
                        },
                        Type = new Type
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Item
            {
                Id = 2,
                Freights = new List<ItemFreight>
                {
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null, 
                        Price = 10, 
                        Days = 8, 
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 3
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 20,
                        Days = 3,
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 8
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = new List<Error>
                        {
                            new Error
                            {
                                Message = "Not found."
                            }
                        }, 
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = new List<Erro>
                        {
                            new Error
                            {
                                Message = "Not found."
                            }
                        },
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 2
                        }
                    },
                    new ItemFreight
                    {
                        Errors = null,
                        Price = 22,
                        Days = 4,
                        Company = new Company 
                        {
                            Id = 7468
                        },
                        Type = new Type 
                        {
                            Id = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

What I need at first is a Linq Query that brings a List where the children List are common between all the Items and doesn't have errors in it.

In this case I have something like:

```
          Company Id     Type Id     Error
Item 1        1             3          N
Item 1        1             8          N
Item 1        2             1          N
Item 1        2             2          N
Item 1       7468           1          N
Item 2        1             3          N
Item 2        1             8          N
Item 2        2             1          Y
Item 2        2             2          Y
Item 2       7468           1          N
```

So in this case I need a list where the combinations would be only the company 1 and 7468 (could be "n" companies). So in item 2 I have errors on my company 2 response, so it has to be eliminated. The result would be:

```
          Company Id     Type Id     Error
Item 1        1             3          N
Item 1        1             8          N
Item 1       7468           1          N
Item 2        1             3          N
Item 2        1             8          N
Item 2       7468           1          N
```

It could happen with any of the combination companies/types, so it has to be some kind of a dynamic query, if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the companies that return an error for any freight:

```
        var errorCompanyIds = response.Items
            .SelectMany(x => x.Freights)
            .Where(y => y.Errors !=null && y.Errors.Any())
            .Select(y => y.Company.Id)
            .ToList();
```

Then you can create your new list and filter any freight from that comapny

```
        var newList = new FreightSimulation
        {
            Items = response.Items.Select(x => new Item
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Freights = x.Freights.Where(y => !errorCompanyIds.Contains(y.Company.Id)).ToList()
            }).ToList()

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var companyIds = new[] { 1, 7468 };
var result = response.Items.SelectMany(i => i.Freights.Select(f => new { itemId = i.Id, Freight = f }))
            .Where(i => companyIds.Contains(i.itemId) && (!(i.Freight.Errors?.Any() ?? false)));
```

What you are doing here is creating pairs to preserve the ids and then filtering those pairs based on your desired criteria.

Alternatively, you can filter the original list of freights first, then pick by company:

```
var companyIds = new[] { 1, 7468 };
var result = response.Items.SelectMany(i => i.Freights.Where(f => (!(f.Errors?.Any() ?? false)))
             .Select(f => new { itemId = i.Id, Freight = f }))
             .Where(i => companyIds.Contains(i.itemId));
```

Just in case this part is a bit confusing:

```
(!(i.Freight.Errors?.Any() ?? false))
```

This essentially translates to:

```
i.Freight.Errors == null || !i.Freight.Errors.Any()
```

Meaning freights with `null` errors or no errors (empty collection).